# How to link compile error to java source in eclipse ide running a maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am quite new to eclipse and want to develop a maven project in java.
Compilation from within eclipse works but
If i get a compilation error on the eclipse console,
there is no link to the source code.
I would expect eclipse to have such a link.
Does it exist? and if so, how to activate it???

Maybe the problem is, that i already have a maven project
and now want to use eclipse on it.

Comment: You should compile in your IDE in such cases ...

Comment: @khmarbaise. Yes I do of course. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing a Maven project in Eclipse, you should create it as a "Maven Project", which will utilize the "m2e" or "maven2eclipse" plugin.  When you do it this way, then Eclipse will use the same source folders your Maven build will use (defaulting to src/main/java and src/test/java), and Eclipse will look at the dependencies specified in the pom.xml file and make sure those dependencies are all downloaded and available for the Eclipse compiler.  If this is all done properly, then if there are any red marks in the project, then those represent the same compile errors that you would get if you built the Maven project from the command line.  Watch out for any red marks in the pom.xml file itself.  When that happens, Eclipse doesn't attempt to compile anything.

Comment: Ah thank you... My situation is, that i already have maven projects, several ones and want to use eclipse now in it. Maybe I did something wrong in importing. 
I remember errors when importing. Still compilation from within eclipse works fine, but no link to source! What shall I do?

Comment: You'll have to show exactly what you've done to set up the project. From the information you've provided, no one could possibly answer this question.